# Getline function is not parsing end of line in CSV file

Tags: c++, file, csv, parsing

I am simply trying to read a CSV file and print it on the terminal, but I think the `getLine()` function is not parsing the end of line character. I thought that it was because the file that I was reading was created on Windows and I was running the script on Linux. To test that theory, I created a new CSV file on Linux, but it is having the same issue.

CSV File:

> ```
> julio,tito,monroy
> felipe,aguilar,jowell
> ```

```
readCsv.open("test.csv", ios::in);
if(readCsv.is_open()){
    string time;
    string in;
    string out;
    int count = 1;

    while(!readCsv.eof()){
        getline(readCsv, time, ',');
        getline(readCsv, in, ',');
        getline(readCsv, out, ',');

        printf("%d : %s %s %s", count, time.c_str(), in.c_str(), out.c_str());

        count++;
    }

} else {
    printf("There was an error when trying to open the csv file. \n");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To read a CSV file, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: I suggest a change of strategy. 1. Read the contents of the file line by line. 2. Process each line using a `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
while (getline(readCsv, time, ',') &&
        getline(readCsv, in, ',') &&
        getline(readCsv, out))
{
```

There are two things wrong with your version. Firstly your third column is terminated by an end of line, not by a comma, so `getline(readCsv, out, ',')` is wrong. Secondly your understanding of how `eof` works is incorrect, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)